# can we open a command prompt from google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to run a command prompt and give message to user on specific conditions.

Conditions/ logic is written in google appscript as we are using Gsuite files, is it possible to open my local command prompt and run a command like we do from powershell or vba.

Comment: No `````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: chrome dev tools?

Answer (score 2):

No, in the way you are defining it that feature is not supported in Apps Script.

**However**, you might have heard of [clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp) which is a command line interface to develop and manage Apps Script projects from your terminal rather than form the Apps Script editor.

You will be able to manage versions of your projects, run, deploy and create scripts and so on. In [this guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/clasp/#0) you can see an overview of all you can do with clasp. This is the [clasp Github repository](https://github.com/google/clasp) in case you are interested in taking a further look.